# Html text input of width 100% slightly overrunning end of containing table cell

Tags: html, css, forms, width

Fairly simple question; I have a table which contains form inputs in HTML and have set one of the elements to span 100% of the width of the table. However, it seems to ever so slightly overrun the end of the cell it is contained in:

https://jsfiddle.net/abz7mtsj/1/

```
.queryinput {
    width:100%;
}
```

it is barely noticeable in the jsfiddle but on my page it is a large table spanning about 80% of the screen so looks very untidy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) property (CSS3) to account for the padding and border. See the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/abz7mtsj/2/). See browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing).

```
.queryinput {
    width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow:hidden` to `td` element in your css:

```
td {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks; that does partially solve it as it now looks like it only goes to the end of the cell. Being extra picky though, when a drop-down appears below the text input (e.g. for previously entered form data that has been remembered) it still shows as longer. Is there a way to make the actual box the right width, rather than just how it appears in the cell?